# Adding a day to React state Date object created using useState

Tags: reactjs

I am having a state object in React which has a Date value.

const [myDate, setMyDate] = useState(new Date());

How do I increment the date by one day using setMyDate() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a different object in `setMyDate` so that React can tell it has been modified, try:

```
setMyDate(date => {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    return new Date(date)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js from npm.

```
setMyDate(moment(myDate).add(1, 'days').format());
```